# type vs interface indexer property in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Could someone explain to me what is the difference between `type` vs `interface` in flow? I have been reading online but could not find an answer.

Here is the code:
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gCyeOxAJsbWAN6phgDWeAngFxgBnHAWwBzANxswAN2IwArnn7Es3SQF902fETIVqtBrQDyAIwBWLKQG0ufQcLEBdfgfqNiG9LIJgAtjTutK6BRsRmlgC8VuwCcAEASnh08uQE-MycPPwARPhCOQA0MnKK-ACMYOqFUipwOAAWhEkpaRlZ9nl4BcWyCkpgAExVNeriQA

For example, the following code works:

```
type Metadata {
  key: string;
  value: any;
}

type MetadataObj {
  [key: string]: Metadata;
}

var metadata: MetadataObj = {
  someReducer: { key: "test", value: 1 },
  anotherReducer: { key: "test", value: 2 },
};
```

But this does not, and produce this error:

> Cannot assign object literal to `metadata` because an indexer property is missing in object literal [1] but exists in `MetadataObj` [2]. (References: [1] [2])

```
interface Metadata {
  key: string;
  value: any;
}

interface MetadataObj {
  [key: string]: Metadata;
}

var metadata: MetadataObj = {
  someReducer: { key: "test", value: 1 },
  anotherReducer: { key: "test", value: 2 },
};
```

I have read similar posts like these, but it does not really help me:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3876

And on Typescript...
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.10

Comment: interfaces are not concrete, they are contracts

Comment: That statement does not really help either. :(